# Local variable 'a_no' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

Can anyone please explain me why I am not able to access `a_no` in `route("/otp")`?

Flask code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,url_for,redirect

parties=["A","B","C","D"]


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('home.html')
    #return render_template('admin.html')
##################################################################
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def my_form_post():
    if request.method == "POST":
       adhar_no = request.form['aadhar_num']

       return redirect(url_for('verification',adhar_no=adhar_no))
    
@app.route('/otp',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def verification():
    if request.method =="GET":
       a_no=request.args.get('adhar_no')
       return render_template("otp.html")
    
    if  request.method == "POST":
         otp_text = request.form['otp']
         
    return a_no
```

I am getting local variable `a_no` referenced before assignment. Can anyone help me to solve this error in route `/otp`?

Comment: If `request.method` doesn't equal "GET" then that variable is not defined...

Answer (score 1):

In your `/otp` route `a_no` is initialized explicitly on `request.method =="GET"` , This initialization will execute only when you browse `/otp` route with `GET` request.

While doing POST `a_no` is uninitialized and still being returned from the route hence the error `local variable 'a_no' referenced before assignment`.

```
@app.route('/otp',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def verification():
    a_no = '' #initialize a_no here
    if request.method == "GET":
       a_no = request.args.get('adhar_no')
       return render_template("otp.html")
    
    if request.method == "POST":
         otp_text = request.form['otp']
         
    return a_no
```

I still don't understand why you are returning `a_no`, If you are trying to maintain the state between request for the same client, consider using [`session`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.session)